# Doubt about linking a local repo to github

Tags: command-line, github

I have created a remote repo named `textfile` in Github and also linked a local folder named `textfile` to git. I want to add a new text file from the folder to github. What are the steps for doing that using the command line in Ubuntu?

I am a beginner to GitHub.

Comment: Does this help? https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and go to your repo directory.
Add files:

```
git add *
```

Commit:

```
git commit -m 'my message'
```

Push it to the Github:

```
git push origin master
```